# Spring REST Body + General Model

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am using `spring 4` REST.

I have a base `class` and many other `class` extends the same. 
For example, Employee is the base `class` and other classes hr, engineer, trainer etc etc extends the employee.

I have to create `REST API` to create the different type of employee. 
The `interface` is one `POST` which accepts all the type of employees. I cannot create different `interface` for each sub type. From the base, I know what is the sub type.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/test/{employeeType}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){

    //If type is HR, I want to cast to HR type
    //Is there any way we can take generic object in spring rest and then manage internally ?

}
```

Comment: Why would you expect different incoming request body structure to the same endpoint?, ideally this should not drive you model classes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/test/{employeeType}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createEmp(@PathVariable String employeeType, @RequestBody EmployeeDTO employeeDTO){
   transform(employeeType,employeeDTO);
}
```

Here EmployeeDTO will contain all possible parameters so it can construct any of the child classes then based on the employeeType you just transform into domain object(Employee)?

Edit2 as requested

Here is sample code:

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
```

}

```
public class Hr extends Employee {

private String department;
```

}

```
public class Hr extends Employee {

private String department;
```

}

Then the DTO class should look like this:

```
public class EmployeeDTO {

private String name;
private String course;
private String department;
```

}

Then when you know your type you transform to whatever your want with all the necessary values in the DTO

Edit: Now when I think about it this also may be an option but I will need to see your classes.

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/test/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createEmp(@RequestBody Employee employee){

@RequestMapping(value= "/test/hr", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createHr(@RequestBody Hr hr){
```

Comment: The second option is not possible for me since the uri will differ for each type.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the firstway